# Will removing short rib bones after cooking dry the meat?

Tags: stock, bones, roast-beef

i'm roasting lots of short rib this weekend in 2 batches and curious to know if removing the bones quickly (for stock) after the 1st batch is cooked and refrigerating the cooked meat while the 2nd batch cooks will dry the meat out at all? i.e. would it be better to leave bones in while it cools down or doesn't make a difference?

Thanks!

Comment: How long are you planning on leaving the first batch out?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I think only for about 12 hours, then i'll reheat and serve them - will this be ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bones will not make a difference in the moisture of your meat, but overcooking will dry your meat.  Make sure you cook and reheat correctly, and you can remove the bones with no problems. (Plenty of folks cook boneless short ribs that are moist!)